# How can I tell if a hard drive will fit my laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I've browsed similar questions on the website but they don't seem to solve my problem. I have a laptop, the MSI GT GT70 0ND-202US, which came with a 750GB HDD (7200RPM). All that I have managed to google about my laptop's hard drive / hard drive slot is that it's a SATA III.

I really don't understand much about hardware, so I my question is: how can I find out if another hard drive (designed for laptops) that is also SATA III will fit my laptop (to replace the current one)?

For example, would this one:

Western Digital Bare Drives 500GB WD Blue SATA III 5400 RPM 8 MB Cache Bulk/OEM Notebook Hard Drive WD5000LPVX

fit?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Verify the physical dimensions of the device

Comment: This is most likely a 2.5" HDD. But why on earth do you want to replace a 7200RPM disk with a 5400RPM disk which is slower. If any, I would replace the HDD with a SSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I've ever seen a laptop with a 3.5" drive bay, but here's confirmation anyway. This site lists the GT70 as using an HGST Travelstar. They are 2.5" drives. Any 2.5" drive will fit this laptop. Enjoy.

http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-MSI-GT70-2PE-890US-Gaming-Notebook.115293.0.html

Comment: Maybe not, standard laptop hard drive is 9.5mm thick or less, which is the standard thickness, some newer hard drives are thicker (15mm) and will not fit the drive bay.